# Permissions required to increment performance counters

Tags: .net, performancecounter

I'm having difficulty determining the permissions needed to increment a performance counter.  I had just one occurance of an InvalidOperationException/Access Denied (I think) when trying to call .Increment on a counter.  This lead me to the following info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555129

> The biggest problem surrounding the process of moving an ASP.NET
>   application that updates performance counters into a production
>   environment is permissions.  By default, in order to increment a
>   performance counter, the user needs to have Administrator or Power
>   User rights.

From there I added the user to the power users group and continued on my way without issue.  It was from an unrelated issue that I later discovered that "Power User" no longer has any permissions beyond Vista and that let me back to that same article:

> Fortunately, given these alternatives, it turns out that the
>   permission set required to update performance counters is much smaller
>   than running as an Administrator or Power User.  In the registry key
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib, set the
>   Access Control List so that the necessary user has Full Control. In
>   our original example, the ASPNET user would be granted Full Control,
>   but access can be granted to anyone who needs to update a performance
>   counter.

But even that doesn't seem to be true as I've now gone back and removed my test user from the power users group and my application is still incrementing counters without issue.

Futher, it seems that if there were permissions to be set, it would be on the individual counter under HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\.

I fully admit that there may have been some other issue with my code that caused my original permissions issue.  However, I need to deploy this all the way back to XP so it's important for me to confirm whether the above is simply dated info or is entirely incorrect.  I'll be able to confirm this myself shortly, but it would be nice if somebody could validate the info or point me to concrete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of permissions here:

1. Permission to modify performance counter category
2. Permission to call modify the performance counter through .NET code

For the first one you only need permissions to modify the registry key  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib (=either add manually or add user to Performance Log Users ect..) and few other things normal user has (e.g. access HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services) as noted in the KB.

The second one is related to Code Access Security (CAS) policy. The CAS policy was/is a mechanism to determine if the executing code has permission for an operation (often on resource, e.g. filesystem or performance counters) and if it didn't, the SecurityExeption was thrown. CAS policy is [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103(v=vs.100).aspx) since .NET 4 due to [various](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2010/02/24/is-cas-dead-in-net-4/) reasons (e.g. there is also native Win32 API beside beside .NET code).

If you want to understand the CAS policy, this is a nice article: [Understanding .NET Code Access Security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5724/Understanding-NET-Code-Access-Security)

When CAS was enabled, it was possible to create a policy about a code that is running on the computer and set if it can increment or set the raw value of the counter or if it can throw a security exception (the possible permissions of performance counter are found in [PerformanceCounterPermissionAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounterpermissionaccess(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Basically if you have .NET 4, you can ignore CAS policy (it has been turned off), with previous versions check the permission of the program using mscorcfg.msc.

Comment: for site with app pool identity LocalSystem what account to add to Performance Log Users ?